# Is it possible to reorganize the frontend of Illustrator using a plugin and the illustrator SDK?

Tags: c++, user-interface, user-experience, adobe-illustrator

I was looking through the SDK docs and it seems its possible, but I'd rather hear from someone that may have already looked into this or have done this for other Adobe apps. Basically I would want to create a plugin that would completely gut the GUI and I would create my own UI framework to use for Illustrator.

Answer (score 2):

You can create plug-ins for Illustrator that add tools, menu items, modal dialogs and panels. You cannot, however, write a plug-in that removes any of Adobe's UI. The only way to remove Adobe functionality is to delete their plug-ins. The problem is that many of them are inter-dependent so removing one may cause another not to work or possibly crash. So, in general, you can add to Illustrator, but you cannot take away from Illustrator.

Comment: The only thing I might add here is that technically it *might* be possible to remove parts of the UI **using platform-specific code**, but otherwise it isn't doable from within the SDK. You would have one hell of a time with all the plug-in and UI interdependencies, though...